# Django Tag System

Tags: python, django

here I have the code, I want to create a post tag or category, I do not want to create a new tag when I already have tags that I have created and sent to the database, with the code below the tag is made duplicate

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Post, through="Tagging")

class Tagging(models.Model):
    posts = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taggings = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post = request.POST['post']
        tag = request.POST['tag']
        posts = Post.objects.create(post=post)
        tags = Tag.objects.create(tag=tag)
        tp = Tagging(posts=posts, taggings=tags)
        tp.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

how to tag not duplicate?

Comment: If you use `get_or_create`method you won't create duplicate tags..

Comment: add it in the models or view? Im very confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `get_or_create` method to avoid creating duplicates. Also, I believe you should move your `ManyToMany` field to the `Post` model.

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', through="Tagging")

class Tagging(models.Model):
    posts = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    taggings = models.ForeignKey('Tag', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

***views.py***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Post, Tag, Tagging


def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post = request.POST['post']
        tag = request.POST['tag']
        posts = Post.objects.create(post=post)
        tags, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(tag=tag)
        tp = Tagging(posts=posts, taggings=tags)
        tp.save()
        return redirect('index')
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: thank you so much, i dont know about method get_or_create.